# How to play 360 video on own web server without using third-party services as youtube?

Tags: video, server, html5-video, 360-virtual-reality

How it is possible to make a web server which will be able to play 360 videos so that once users enter it via mobile phone or whatever which has sensors was able to control it?

Of course I want to implement it without using youtube or other video hosting web sites.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There are several different players available which are capable of 360° video playback. If you are searching for an open source solution, the [eleVR Web Player](http://player.elevr.com/), or the JS library from [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) might be an option.

A commercial alternative (comes also with a free plan) is the [Bitmovin Player](https://bitmovin.com/player/).